# MUI custom theme not applying

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply a custom MUI theme using a context provider, but the theme is not being applied in child components.

Here is my palette code:

```
import React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { orange } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: orange,
    secondary: {
      main: "#000000",
    },
  },
});

export default function Palette({ children }) {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
}
```

And here is my custom button that uses it:

```
import React from "react";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Palette from "../Themes/Palette";

export default function IconButton({ icon }) {
  return (
    <Palette>
      <Button
        sx={{
          width: 60,
          height: 60,
          borderRadius: "50%",
        }}
        variant="contained"
      >
        <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
      </Button>
    </Palette>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using different versions of `material-ui` library. If you use `@material-ui` then it means you are using v4. If you use `@mui` then it means you are using v5.

You should change:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { orange } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
```

to:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { orange } from "@mui/material/colors";
```

and you should also change:

```
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
```

to:

```
import Icon from "@mui/material/Icon";
```

You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-custom-theme?file=src%2FIconButton.js) for a live working example.

You might also take a look at [Migration from v4 to v5](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/).

Answer (score 5):

People who have tried literally everything but their styles are still not applying please **remove all mui and styling packages and reinstall them**. There might be some conflicting packages which are making mui buggy. I spent 2 days stuck on applying a custom theme, then finally did this. It worked obv that's why I am writing this answer.
Peace.

Comment: different emotion versions in our monorepo were the reason for me

Answer (score 3):

Go through this migration docs it might help you

https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

i added **Emotion10ThemeProvider** then theme changes reflected in UI

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { ThemeProvider as Emotion10ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';

const defaultTheme = createTheme(); // or your custom theme

 <Emotion10ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <Story {...context} />
    </ThemeProvider>
 </Emotion10ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: This helped me find the Storybook v6 workaround which was my issue, thank you!

Comment: It works. Moreover, `ThemeProvider` from `@mui` can be removed, it does nothing at all.
It's super weird.