# MUI theme is not applied

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm new to MUI and I am having trouble with applying custom theme. I was trying to have a new variant for the button that could provide it and used the following piece of code

```
// @ts-nocheck
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
    dashed: true;
  }
}


const MyContainer: FC = (props: any) => {
  
  const defaultTheme = createTheme();
  const myTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiButton: {
        variants: [
          {
            props: { variant: 'dashed1' },
            style: {
              textTransform: 'none',
              border: `2px dashed ${defaultTheme.palette.primary.main}`,
              color: defaultTheme.palette.primary.main,
            },
          },
          {
            props: { variant: 'dashed1', color: 'secondary' },
            style: {
              border: `2px dashed ${defaultTheme.palette.secondary.main}`,
              color: defaultTheme.palette.secondary.main,
            },
          },
          {
            props: { variant: 'dashed1', size: 'large' },
            style: {
              borderWidth: 4,
            },
          },
          {
            props: { variant: 'dashed1', color: 'secondary', size: 'large' },
            style: {
              fontSize: 18,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
  return 
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
   <Button variant='dashed1'>HIII</Button>
   </ThemeProvider>
};

export default MyContainer;
```

When I inspect the the button I do see class MuiButton-dashed being applied but there is no CSS corresponding to it. Also, if I dont ignore the typescript errors for the I file I get error implying dashed1 cannot be used as a variant.

I also tried the solutions mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873793/mui-custom-theme-not-applying) but didn't help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to use a MUI custom theme, but there are some problems, like in the theme variant you named it `dashed1`, but in the ButtonPropsVariantOverrides interface declaration, you're naming it `dashed`. These names should match.

```
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
    interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
        dashed1: true;
    }
}
```

Make sure you use the same name everywhere.

Comment: This does resolve the typescript errors bu doesn't help with the css I am trying to apply

Comment: Try to replace `style` with `styleOverrides`, because you're overriding the style so...

Comment: The variant I am using here isn't provided by MUI Button so why do I have to override the styles? Also, it didn't work by applying this change :(

Comment: Please ensure that you have properly set up your development environment, installed the necessary dependencies (@mui/material, @mui/styles, etc.), and that there are no conflicting CSS rules or styles being applied elsewhere in your application that might be affecting the custom variant's styles.